# Import into MySQL from SQL file, but only rows where field = value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqlimport

Is there a way from /usr/bin/mysql or /usr/bin/mysqlimport to import a sql file but exclude all rows where a specific field doesn't have a specific value?

I want to restore data from backup, but only backup data where the field "origin" has the value "import". So I have a script that first deletes all rows in the live database "where origin = 'import'" and then I want to import from a file all those rows that I have backed up, but not every single row, since there are other origins in the backup.

Am I making myself clear? Any ideas?

Comment: One idea is to run the entire sql script, then delete rows where origin <> 'import'. (This is assuming all values are inserted into the same table). But this is a bad practice when the number of rows are too large. But just a thought off the top of my head.

Comment: This will destroy all the data that exists in the database before the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. Prepare the sqlfile by adding a where clause to each statement. Should be 
      relatively easy with your favorite scripting language.
2. Import to a temp "schema" and for each table:

   ```
   insert into realtable 
   select * from temptable where origin = 'import';
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, it's an added couple of steops and I assume the question is that no - it can't be done "native".

Comment: Not sure how I am to create a temp table that matches the data in the sql file though. I would have to first check the format for the existing table and create an identical table in a temp location I suppose. Or is there a way to create a temp table to match the data in the sql file in an easier way?

Comment: `create table tmp_table1 like table1;`

Comment: If it's all tables that have a column named origin something like: `select 'create table tmp_' || table_name || ' like ' || table_name || ';' from information_schema.columns where table_schema = '<yourdb>' and column_name = 'origin';` will give you the create statements that you need